# Restrict number of logging in devices at a time

Tags: configuration, login

I have a scenario that system has to restrict the number of logging in devices of a user at a time.
It means at a time, user just can log in on one device.
How can I configure that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I mean when a user logged in on a phone, after that, the user logged in on a tablet, system will log out the session on phone. It means I want to keep only one active session for each user at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use login flows. Please refer to [THESE DOCS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_limit_concurrent_sessions.htm) for what is involved and how-to. Hope this helps.

Comment: You might explain more about how login flows could be used to achieve the desired results, rather than just a link. How does using Login Flows resolve the problem at hand?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My purpose is notifying and logging out the current session for the new one. I think your suggest is a good solution for my question. Thanks a lot.